# submit array to database with form fields when form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I have my site linked to another sites database, 
I have a form which has fields to submit a query to the external database. 
The query will be similar to

```
SELECT src, timestamp FROM files WHERE uploader_id = 1
```

The query will retrun an array similar to

```
Array (   
[0] => Array ( [src] => http://externaldatabase/0.jpg [created] => 1111111111 ) 
[1] => Array ( [src] => http://externaldatabase/1.jpg [created] => 1111111111 ) 
[2] => Array ( [src] => http://externaldatabase/2.jpg [created] => 1111111111 )
[3] => Array ( [src] => http://externaldatabase/3.jpg [created] => 1111111111 ) 
)
```

Etc for all files retreived.

I have a database on my site 
where im trying to write these values to with other values retrieved from the form.

So the table columns would be

```
fid     uid     uri     timestamp
```

the uri would be the src, the timestamp is created. the fid auto increments by 1, and the uid would be the id of the user that submitted the form.

How do I add my own variables such as the user who submitted the form to the original array returned from the query so I can populate the table.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
if $_POST

    if isset($_POST['uploader_id'])

        $image = [SELECT src, timestamp FROM files WHERE uploader_id = 1]

        foreach $images as $uri
            insert into myDatabaseTable (uid, uri, timestamp) values ($_POST['uid'], $uri, date('YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s')
        endforeach

    else

        // however you want to handle form validation

    endif
endif
```